# Responsive drop downs not activating until resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

So I have tried to setup a responsive menu using the code here
http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/378_tessa/tessa-lt-dropdowns-21c7868/index.html

The problem I'm having is that the js seems to only activate when I resize the browser otherwise the larger version does not show the sub menu li when hovering and the smaller version has the li showing without clicking them first.

**JS**

```
var ww = '100%';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav li a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("parent");
        };
    })

    $(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".nav").toggle();
    });
    adjustMenu();
})

$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    adjustMenu();
});

var adjustMenu = function() {
    if (ww < 768) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
        if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".nav").hide();
        } else {
            $(".nav").show();
        }
        $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(".nav li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
            // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
        });
    } 
    else if (ww >= 768) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");
        $(".nav").show();
        $(".nav li").removeClass("hover");
        $(".nav li a").unbind('click');
        $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
            // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
            $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        });
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
body, nav, ul, li, a  {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
a {text-decoration: none;}
.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.toggleMenu {
    display:  none;
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav {
    list-style: none;
     *zoom: 1;
     background:#175e4c;
}
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
.nav:after {
    clear: both;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9em;
}
.nav a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav li {
    position: relative;
}
.nav > li {
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #104336;
}
.nav > li > .parent {
    background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
}
.nav li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.nav > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
.nav li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.nav li li a {
    display: block;
    background: #1d7a62;
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    border-top: 1px solid #175e4c;
}
.nav li li li a {
    background:#249578;
    z-index:200;
    border-top: 1px solid #1d7a62;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .active {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .nav > li > .parent {
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .nav li li .parent {
        background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .nav ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
   .nav > li.hover > ul , .nav li li.hover ul {
        position: static;
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container"> 
    <a class="toggleMenu" href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Shoes</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Womens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sandals</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sneakers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wedges</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Heels</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Flats</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sneakers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Formal</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Shirts</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dress Shirts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tank Tops</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Womens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blouses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dress Shirts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tunics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Camisoles</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Pants</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Slacks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Womens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Slacks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leggings</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Skirts</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Long</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Denim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Knits</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Short</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Denim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Knits</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mini</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Denim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Knits</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Dresses</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Casual</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Formal</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Wedding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Party</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sweaters</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Wool</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Light Sweaters</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cardigans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hoodies</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Womens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Wool</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Light Sweaters</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cardigans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hoodies</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Accessories</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Womens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Belts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bags</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jewelery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Eyewear</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Belts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Eyewear</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Outerwear</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Womens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Winter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Spring/Fall</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mens</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Winter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Spring/Fall</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Shipping Info</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, on Firefox 28.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. This is some sloppy looking jQuery for something that could be mostly handled in CSS with some :hovers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of `ww` is `'100%'`, which is a string. 
On `$(document).ready` you call the `adjustMenu()` method, which reads the value of `ww`. 
Both conditions (`ww < 768` and `ww >= 768`) evaluate to false, so `adjustMenu()` does nothing on DOMready.

You can avoid this to call `$(window).trigger('resize')` instead of calling `adjustMenu()` in your `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` method so that `ww` has a numeric value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".nav li a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("parent");
        };
    })

    $(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".nav").toggle();
    });

    $(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
       ww = document.body.clientWidth;
       adjustMenu();
    });

    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```